# Modeling an Electrolyzer System

Tags: energy, electricity, simulations, intensity

In this [study](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212017314001686), the authors provide an equation for operating cell voltage: $V_{cell} = V_{rev} + V_{act} + V_{ohm}$, the sum of the reversible overvoltage, the activation overvoltage and the ohmic overvoltage of electrolyte. The authors define $V_{act} := s\log\left(\frac{t_1 + \frac{t_2}{T} + \frac{t_3}{T^2}}{A}I + 1 \right)$ and $V_{ohm} = \frac{r_1 + r_2T}{A}I$.

$s, t_1, t_2, t_3, T, A, r_1, r_2$ are all defined clearly in the study (linked above, they have a parameters chart). However, $I$ is not defined (should be the current in amps). The authors use the equation of empirical current-voltage. How is $I$ defined in the study? Thanks.

Comment: Is $I$ the Current Density, $mA/cm^2$